# buscar elementos de una pila c++

Tags: c++, pilas, búsquedas

Buenas noches tengo el codigo de un trabajo practico con las opcones de ingresar elementos a una pila y buscar, al buscar dicho numero tengo que extraer todos aquellos que sean divisibles por el mismo numero ingresado.Aqui esta el codigo, no funciona la parte donde se filtran los datos divisibles por el mismo numero.

Nota: es en la fuincion void buscar(); esta comentado muchas gracias. El codigo anda bien. excepto por la parte ya comentada.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
struct pilas
{
    int valor;
    pilas *direccionA;
};
pilas *pilao,*pilaaux;
void ingreso();
void mostrar();
//void eliminar();
void buscar();
int main()
{
    int opcion;
    while(true){
        cout<<"1 Ingreso de datos a la pila"<<endl;
        cout<<"2 Leer datos de la pila"<<endl;
        //cout<<"3 Eliminar datos de la pila"<<endl;
        cout<<"3 Buscar datos en la pila"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;
        switch(opcion){
            case 1:{
                ingreso();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                mostrar();
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                buscar();
                break;
            }
            //case 4:{

            //}


        }
    }
}
void ingreso(){
    if(pilao==NULL){
        pilao=new(pilas);
        cout<<"Mi Direccion "<<pilao<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese PRIMER dato a la pila"<<endl;
        cin>>pilao->valor;
        cout<<"Dato ingresado correctamente"<<endl;
        pilao->direccionA=NULL;
        cout<<"Direccion Anterior "<<pilao->direccionA<<endl;
        return;
    }
    pilaaux=new(pilas);
    cout<<"Ingrese dato a la pila"<<endl;
    cout<<"Mi Direccion "<<pilaaux<<endl;
    cin>>pilaaux->valor;
    cout<<"Dato ingresado correctamente"<<endl;
    pilaaux->direccionA=pilao;
    cout<<"Direccion Anterior "<<pilaaux->direccionA<<endl;
    pilao=pilaaux;
}
void mostrar(){
    if(pilao==NULL){
        cout<<"No hay datos en la pila"<<endl;
    }
    pilaaux=pilao;
    cout<<"Los datos de la pila son: "<<endl;
    while(pilaaux!=NULL){
        cout<<pilaaux->valor<<endl;
        pilaaux=pilaaux->direccionA;
    }
    cout<<"FIN"<<endl;
}
//void eliminar(){
//  if(pilao==NULL){
//      cout<<"No hay datos en la pila"<<endl;
//      return;
//  }
//  pilaaux=new(pilas);
//  pilaaux=pilao;
//  cout<<"Elemento eliminado "<<pilaaux->valor<<endl;
//  pilao=pilaaux->direccionA;
//  delete(pilaaux);
//}
void buscar(){
    int num, i;
    if(pilao==NULL){
        cout<<"La pila esta vacia"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    int buscardatos;
    bool encontrado=false;
    pilaaux=pilao;
    cout<<"Ingrese dato a buscar"<<endl;
    cin>>buscardatos;

    num=buscardatos;
    cout<<num<<endl;

    while(pilaaux!=NULL){

        if(buscardatos==pilaaux->valor){
            cout<<"Encontrador, el valor es; "<<pilaaux->valor<<endl;
            encontrado=true;
        if(num%num==0) //extraer los datos divisibles por el valor ingresado
        {
        for(i=0; i<num; i++)
        {

        pilaaux=new(pilas);
        pilaaux=pilao;
        cout<<"Elemento eliminado "<<pilaaux->valor<<endl;
        pilao=pilaaux->direccionA;
        delete(pilaaux);
        }
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"No hay numeeros divisibles"<<endl;
        }
            break;
        }
        pilaaux=pilaaux->direccionA;

    if(encontrado==false){
    cout<<"No se encontro el valor"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es:

```
DatoPila = SacaUnDatoDeTuPila;
   While(pilaaux!=NULL){
     if(DatoPila %  DatoActualDeLaPila = 0){ // Si no tiene reciduo quiere decir que si es divisible
      cout << "Es divisible";
      pilaaaux.pop(); //Sacara el elemento de tu Pila
    }      
 else{
        cout << "NoEs divisible";
       }

    }
```

Comment: Has puesto una asignación, no una comparación...